# SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

I have problem with `AutoCompleteTextView`. I have `ListView` consisting of AutoCompleteTextView and EditText for some number input which I can modify to dynamically add rows. Everything works fine for first row, but when I add second row and try to type into AutoCompleteTextView the keyboard loses focus and I cannot type anything. Here is my class that uses this listview:

```
public class AddMealActivity extends Activity {

String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };

EditText mealNameTextView;
ListView mealPartsListView;
Meal meal;
MealPartCustomAdapter mealPartsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_meal);
    mealNameTextView =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mealNameTextView);
    mealPartsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mealPartsListView);
    meal = new Meal();
    mealPartsAdapter = new MealPartCustomAdapter(this, meal.mealParts);
    mealPartsListView.setAdapter(mealPartsAdapter);
}

public void onOkMealClick(View view) {
    meal.mealName = mealNameTextView.getText().toString();
    meal.mealParts = mealPartsAdapter._mealParts;
    finish();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("Meal", meal);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    super.finish();
}

public void onAddMealPartButtonClick(View view) {
    mealPartsAdapter.add(new MealPart());
}

private static class MealPartCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<MealPart> _mealParts;
    private Context _context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    static class ViewHolder {
        AutoCompleteTextView productNameTextView;
        EditText foodQuantityEditText;
    }

    public void add(MealPart mealPart) {
        _mealParts.add(mealPart);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public MealPartCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MealPart> mealParts) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        _mealParts = new ArrayList<MealPart>(mealParts);
        _context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _mealParts.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return _mealParts.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_meal_list_view_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productNameTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.
                    findViewById(R.id.mealPartAutoCompleteTextView);
            holder.foodQuantityEditText = (EditText) convertView.
                    findViewById(R.id.mealQuantityEditText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.foodQuantityEditText
            .setText(Utilities.trimDecimalsToString(_mealParts.get(position).foodQuantity));
        holder.foodQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(new FoodQuantityTextWatcher(position, holder.foodQuantityEditText));

        //TODO here fetch real product names from web API
        //TODO on item selected - pass to mealPart proudctId of chosen product
        ArrayAdapter<String> productNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DATA);
        holder.productNameTextView.setAdapter(productNamesAdapter);
        holder.productNameTextView.addTextChangedListener(new ProductNameTextWatcher(position,holder.productNameTextView));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ProductNameTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private int index;
        private AutoCompleteTextView edittext;
        public ProductNameTextWatcher(int index, AutoCompleteTextView edittext) { 
                   this.index = index; 
                   this.edittext = edittext;
            }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  _mealParts.get(index).productName = s.toString();      }
        public void setIndex(int newindex) {  index = newindex;    }
    }

    private class FoodQuantityTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private int index;
        private EditText edittext;
        public FoodQuantityTextWatcher(int index, EditText edittext) { 
                   this.index = index; 
                   this.edittext = edittext;
            }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
            try {
                _mealParts.get(index).foodQuantity = Float.valueOf(s.toString());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                _mealParts.get(index).foodQuantity = 0.0f;
            }
        }
        public void setIndex(int newindex) {  index = newindex;    }
    }
```

When I try to touch field on my device logcat says:

**12-31 03:04:11.300: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29494): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length**

I would like to add that losing focus happens on my **Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300** with stock 4.1.2 onboard. On **Genymotion** emulator (the same phone emulated) this doesn't happen.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also stuck in the same problem ...

Comment: No, I have changed implementation to use LinearLayout and populate manually layout with rows, I don't use ListView anymore. I guess there is some bug.

Comment: Did you get also this error: 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` ?

Comment: No, that's because your array is of size 0. The problem must be in your code.